# docker-compose: How to stop,remove the containers and networks and restart

Tags: docker-compose

How to use `docker-compose` to restart with deleting all its containers and networks.

Just like a fresh `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below

```sh
docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

Comment: but this does not take care if the docker-compose.yml file is changed

Comment: For that you would need to add `--build` as well